# Passing disbaled input fields values to apex controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, inputfield

I have a JavaScript function that fills some `apex:inputfields` and make them disabled so the user cannot change their values.
But it seems that values aren't passed to the controller after an action (`commandButton`)
I tried by removing the part in the JavaScript function which disables the inputs and it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried marking them read-only instead?

**Edit** As pointed out by eyescream in the comments, disabled fields are not sent on form submission. His link has more detail on that topic.

Comment: +1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730695/whats-the-difference-between-disabled-disabled-and-readonly-readonly-for-te